# Замер времени исполения плейбука для отдельного хоста

Tags: ansible

Добрый вечер.

Возник такой травильный вопрос, пока еще не встречал адекватного решения.

Как посчитать затраченное время на проигрыш плейбука для каждого хоста, требуется для составления отчетного сообщения в Телеграмм.

Пока вот такая заглушка, не всегда показывает правильное время, если плейбук выполнен параллельно для нескольких хостов:

*pl-signoff.yml*

```
#!/usr/bin/ansible-playbook
- hosts: _signoff
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    - playbook_name: "pl-signoff"
    - build_version: 1.41 

  pre_tasks:
    - local_action: shell date
      register: pl_begin
      become: false

  roles:
    - role-1
    - role-2
    # etc
    - inspector
```

*roles/inspector/tasks/main.yml*

```
- name: "last probe of facts"
  setup:

- local_action: shell date
  register: pl_end
  become: false

- name: "shout it loud to signoff_test"
  telegram:
    msg_format: plain
    token: 'my_tocken'
    chat_id: my_id
    msg: |
         BEGIN: "{{ pl_begin }}"
         PL: "{{ playbook_name }}"
         MSG: task complete for the site "{{ site-id }}"
         END: "{{ pl_end }}"
```

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдёт подход из [этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/company/d2cio/blog/343368/)?

Comment: > TASK [debug]
> **************************** ok: [azs00-srv] => msg:
> - pl-signoff
> - 1.41
> - '1633427521'
> - '2021-10-05T09:52:01.780336Z' Вот он выводит это, а где показывает время затраченное на время проигрывания? Тоже нигде не могу найти как сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все на много проще оказалось, просто запустил предварительные задания на локальной машине и собрал факты о времени:

```
- hosts: _signoff
  gather_facts: false


  pre_tasks:
    - name: "setup localhost"
      local_action: setup gather_subset=min
      become: false
    - name: "set meta facts"
      set_fact:
        pl_name: "pl-signoff"
        pl_version: 1.41
        pl_build: "{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}"
        pl_begin: "{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_micro }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
        - "{{ pl_name }}"
        - "{{ pl_version }}"
        - "{{ pl_build }}"
        - "{{ pl_begin }}"
```

Получаем очень точное время запуска плейбука для каждого хоста:

```
Tuesday 02 January 2018  23:53:04 +0000 (0:00:00.053)       0:00:00.773 ******* 
ok: [TEST-SiteUbuntu-16-04] => {
    "msg": [
        "pl-signoff", 
        1.41, 
        "1514937183", 
        "2018-01-02T23:53:03.820574Z"
    ]
}
ok: [TEST-SiteUbuntu-12-04] => {
    "msg": [
        "pl-signoff", 
        1.41, 
        "1514937183", 
        "2018-01-02T23:53:03.817155Z"
    ]
}
```

**Ссылки**

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/set_fact_module.html
- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/setup_module.html